# В каких случаях надо писать что то в теле деструктора?

Tags: c#, деструктор

В каких случаях надо писать что то в теле деструктора ? Когда нам самим руками на особождать ресурсы?
Уже пишу год на c# не когда не писал что в деструкторе.

```
class Person
{
public: 
    Person(string n)
    {
        name = n;
    }
    ~Person()
    {
        Debug.Log( "Destructor called for Person " + name );
    }
private:
    string name;
};
```

Comment: `std::` - это из C++. В C# такого нет, если что.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov  переписал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[вот](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/8.2.php)

Большинство объектов, используемых в программах на C#, относятся к управляемым или managed-коду, и легко очищаются сборщиком мусора. Однако вместе с тем встречаются также и такие объекты, которые задействуют неуправляемые объекты (низкоуровневые файловые дескрипторы, сетевые подключения и т.д.). Такие неуправляемые объекты обращаются к API операционной системы через службы PInvoke. Сборщик мусора может справиться с управляемыми объектами, однако он не знает, как удалять неуправляемые объекты. В этом случае разработчик должен сам реализовывать механизмы очистки на уровне программного кода.

Освобождение неуправляемых ресурсов подразумевает реализацию одного из двух механизмов:

- Создание деструктора
- Реализация классом интерфейса System.IDisposable

Comment: Где посмотреть список не управляемых объектов Unity?

Comment: @IvanTriumphov - смотрите, реализует ли тип интерфейс `IDisposable`